# Is there a way to commit artifacts tfs from jenkins build

Tags: tfs, jenkins, continuous-integration

It very easy using the TFS Plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Team+Foundation+Server+Plugin) to check detect code changes committed to TFS, check out the code and compile it using Jenkins.

However I need to check a build artifact back into TFS after the build is complete. I can't see an option to do this.

Is there a way to commit artifacts tfs from jenkins build

Comment: I found no evidence in the plug-in Wiki & Jira that anyone plans working on this. I really hope that this feature will be added to the plugin soon.

Answer (score -1):

This link might prove useful.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/05/27/continuous-deploymentdelivery-with-jenkins-and-vs-team-services/

It's Developer Tools Blogs > Microsoft Application Lifecycle Management article which shows how to set up a Jenkins project that archives artifacts on TFS.
It's titled "Continuous deployment/delivery with Jenkins and VS Team Services" by Anand Gaurav...Really easy to follow and each step is carefully explained.

Comment: sorry about that Peter...i have added some context to it now.